# Can I Read Input Data and create generalized C++ data structure?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, boost, input

I'm trying to generalize a data structure (in C++) such that I can convert input data into a more usable form, and it seems that each different approach I attempt runs into obvious issues that make it unusable.  My research here has helped point out those problems, but it hasn't helped me find a solution to the problem.

For brevity's sake, here's the actual problem.  Each data point comes in as a pair - one string and one unknown data type (most likely either a string, a double or an integer).  The first string will be of the character `X.Y(1).Z`, but that format is not standardized (some will look like `X.Y.Z(A)(1)` or `X(1).Y`, for example).  (The values in the parens there are vector indices as ints or mappings as different "sub-variables" like [A, B, C].)

I'm trying to restructure it into a data structure tree sort of "on the fly" so that I can access it easily (i.e. without reference to the original, potentially lengthy string) and generically (I don't know that string at compile time and therefore can't simply prepare for it).

So far, I've settled on using an `unordered_map<string, (some type T here)>` for the root of the "tree" and a `pair<(some type T), boost::variant>` type seems like an appropriate way to handle that "leaf" at the bottom.

My question is this: is there any way in which I can generalize the structure from that `unordered_map` at the top through the intermediate levels down to the `pair`s at the bottom such that this will work for any string - whether it be `X.Y.Z` or the more complicated cases above?  Or will I need to write my generalization at a higher level (pointer to a generic data object that has multiple possible derived incarnations, for example)?  Or am I totally on the wrong track here?

Unfortunately, I can't show any of the actual data due to its proprietary nature, but the `X.Y(1).Z` format should present the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is underspecified, but reminds me of Boost PropertyTree - which is able to read generic-valued tree-structured input in a variety of formats.

If you can vary the format a little bit you can get results quickly. An example speaks a thousand words:

Input

```
; an int
X.Y(1).Z 42

; a float
X.Y.Z(A)(1) 3.1415926

; a string
X(1).Y "Hello world"

subtree {
    X(2).Y Bye
}
```

Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97af7337cecdacd5)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    using tree = boost::property_tree::ptree;
    tree pt;

    read_info("input.txt", pt);

    std::cout << "The float is " << pt.get<double>(tree::path_type("X.Y.Z(A)(1)", '|')) << "\n";

    write_ini(std::cout  << "\nINI:\n",  pt);
    write_info(std::cout << "\nINFO:\n", pt);
    write_json(std::cout << "\nJSON:\n", pt);

    std::cout << "Greeting: " << pt.get(tree::path_type("subtree|X(2).Y", '|'), "No greeting") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Final words: " << pt.get(tree::path_type("subtree|missing|final.words", '|'), "No final words") << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
The float is 3.14159

INI:
X.Y(1).Z=42
X.Y.Z(A)(1)=3.1415926
X(1).Y=Hello world
[subtree]
X(2).Y=Bye

INFO:
X.Y(1).Z 42
X.Y.Z(A)(1) 3.1415926
X(1).Y "Hello world"
subtree
{
    X(2).Y Bye
}

JSON:
{
    "X.Y(1).Z": "42",
    "X.Y.Z(A)(1)": "3.1415926",
    "X(1).Y": "Hello world",
    "subtree": {
        "X(2).Y": "Bye"
    }
}

Greeting: Bye
Final words: No final words
```

Notes:

- note how you can go without specifying the type for `get<>` if you pass a suitable default value
- note how it's a bit unfortunate that `'.'` is the default path separator in Boost Property Tree paths. Therefore the way to query is a bit clumsy (with `tree::path_type("X(1).Y", '|')` instead of just `"X(1).Y"` e.g.)

Comment: Sorry for under-specification of the problem.  I am trying to give as detailed a description as I can without violating any of the rules regarding sensitive data here.

This actually looks very promising for what I'm working on.  I'll have to explore it and come back with any questions that arise (that can't be answered by [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/property_tree.html), of course).  Thanks.